# Qt Creator adds an invisible character in Fake Vim mode when it loses the focus

Tags: qt, qt-creator, fakevim

As you may know you can activate **Fake Vim** mode in **Qt Creator** with Alt+V, Alt+v. But when I activate it in my Fedora machine, I see kind of strange behaviour.  Every thing is OK but when I switch to another program or even when I open a new window in creator ( I mean when editor loses the focus ) a new invisible character is added to my editor and I can't compile the source code anymore! You can see this situation in the picture bellow. Is it kind of bug? When I delete that character every thing becomes normal.
[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because SO isn't Qt project's bugtracker.

Comment: Got to the [bugtracker](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTCREATORBUG) and check if there's a bugreport for this. If not, log in (or sign up) and report a new issue.